How to minimize function with extra condition in Octave?
I want to solve a problem of finding a point on a curve (which represents a river of a shape given by the curve) so that person can travel in minimum time from point A to point B which are located on different sides of a curve. The velocities of the person on the land and in the water are known and there is also the water current velocity. I tried to use fminbnd function at first and this is what I got. My function looks like this:
  function res = maliboo(fshore,Vr,x0,x1,Vb,Vw)

  x = linspace(x0(1)-2, x1(1)+2);
  y = fshore(x);
  plot(x,y)
  ylim([min(min(y), x1(2))-1 max(max(y), x0(1))+1])
  hold on
  plot(x0(1), x0(2), 'o')
  plot(x1(1), x1(2), '*')
  v2 = sqrt(Vr.^2+Vw.^2);

  t = @(xx) (sqrt((x0(1) - xx).^2 + (fshore(xx)-x0(2)).^2))./ Vb + (sqrt((x1(1) - xx).^2 + (fshore(xx)-x1(2)).^2))./ v2;
  xxx = fminbnd(t, x0(1), x1(1));
##  h = @(xx) fshore(xx + (x1(1)-xx)/2) - (x1(2)-fshore(xx))/(x1(1)-xx) * (xx + (x1(1)-xx)/2) - fshore(xx)-((x1(2)-fshore(xx))/(x1(1)-xx))*xx;
##  xxx = sqp((x1(1)-x0(1))/2, t);
  plot(xxx, fshore(xxx), 'x')
  plot([x0(1) xxx], [x0(2) fshore(xxx)], '--', 'linewidth', 2)
  plot([xxx x1(1)], [fshore(xxx) x1(2)], '--', 'linewidth', 2)


fshore is function handle that determines the boundary shape; Vr, Vb, Vw - speeds; x0, x1 - starting and ending points

The problem is that the second part of the path should be below the curve. I also tried to use sqp function and the resulting point turned out a bit different. I am not sure what condition should I add here to get the desired path. I wouldn't want to use any extra packages though...
Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

This isn't valid MATLAB code, so I'm assuming you're using Octave. Please don't use both tags - an answer which works in MATLAB might not help you at all in Octave
